# Is there any live customer support service that actually uses Gmail for answering?

Tags: html, gmail

I'm looking for a service that can implement live customer support, like some kind of live chat, but that doesn't have to have someone online in a platform, but can receive tickets and messages in Gmail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any person interested, I found my solution at [Zopim](https://www.zopim.com/). They have really good support and the feature I was looking for is already implemented.

You can link the live support with any IM Messenger you want, and therefore you are not obliged to have someone logged in a platform, so as to offer live chat to your visitors.